# Second async await function is not calling

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, fs

I am trying to unzip a file first and then await for that unzipping file to be complete before i loop through each file and upload it to an S3 bucket. The first function `unzipPromise` is running fine, and everything is getting unzipped in the proper directory, but the `uploadS3Promise` is not running at all. I am not getting errors through this process, it just runs and unzips the file and never touches the `uploadS3Promise` function.

```
function unzipInput(file, client, project_number, oldpath, newpath) {
    path = `zips/${client}/${project_number}/${file}/`;
    function unzipPromise() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            fse.mkdirsSync(path);
            fs.rename(oldpath, newpath, err => {
                if (err) {
                    throw err;
                }
            });
            fs.createReadStream(newpath).pipe(unzip.Extract({ path }));
        });
    }
    function uploadS3Promise() {
        console.log("running");
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            // fs.unlinkSync(newpath);
            fs.readdirSync(newpath).forEach(file => {
                uploadToS3(file, client, project_number, path);
                console.log(file, "test");
            });

            if (err) reject(err);
            else resolve("success");
        });
    }
    // New code with async:
    (async () => {
        try {
            await unzipPromise();
            await uploadS3Promise();
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e);
        }
    })();
}
```

Comment: You never call `resolve()` in your first promise so it gets awaited forever.

Comment: Is `uploadToS3` asynchronous? If not, your `uploadS3Promise` should not create a promise at all because it is entirely synchronous.

Answer (score 0):

uploadS3Promise doesn't run because the code is still *await*ing for unzipPromise to complete. The code will not execute further unless you *resolve* or *reject* a promise.

So in you code ...

```
function unzipPromise(){
    ...
    resolve(...)
    ...
}
```

On an unrelated note, I think it would be more readable not to name function names end in promise. Like just call them unzip and uploadS3. We don't name our function usually by return types right, like we never say intIndexOf, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You supposed to call `resolve` after unzip path is done or `reject` if error occured.
And since streams are EventEmitter, you can listen to events and interact with it

```
const stream = fs.createReadStream(newpath).pipe(unzip.Extract({ path }))
stream
.on('error', (err) => reject(err))
.on('finish', () => resolve())
```

Answer (score -1):

Personally, I'd use a .then to break the process down a bit.

```
unzipPromise().then(res => {
    console.log('resolved promise 1');
    uploadS3Promise();
} rej => {
    console.log('rejected promise 1, sorry!');
});
```

Also- "unzipInput" is never resolved or rejected.

Comment: what difference would it make if promise is never resolved? `ascyn-await` are better to handle promise than `then` waterfall callbacks.

Comment: I suggested a .then because in my experience they are easier to debug. They don't have to stay, but the point is you can console.log at each step of the process and find the break. You can do the same with await, but then you'll need to assign it to a var and check it. Doesn't really matter honestly the first await is never going to return and it's going to await forever.

Comment: with `.then` we are creating variable by default and a callback function. also if need to call `async` function from a for loop `.then()` wont be able to help. like `async { for loop result.push(await multipleCalls) }`. Talking about debugging it's just what one is in habit of using. I moved from `callback` to `async.js` to `promise and .then()` to `async-await` and finally `generators`. I like `generators` above all.

Comment: Ah, yeah I didn't even know `await` existed until today. So `.then` just seems more natural to me. I wish I knew this while writing my last app! xD

Comment: I can't believe how quick people are to down vote an answer (Even though it rightfully deserved it), yet I write a handful of other answers that were pretty good (and most likely helped the user as they didn't write anything back) and no one bothers to up-vote. C'mon, I just want some rep! Does answers down-voted impact the user at all?

Comment: No it doesn't, those who down vote there reps get down by 2 too. I need reps to and I have answers with marked as solution but no up vote.

Comment: I have given one line answers that work but still down vote. and worst is down vote with no comment why I got down vote